# Python Else Pass

Tags: python, if-statement

Hey got a small script what should check the code of a bunch of pages and send a msg via pushbullet if a specific string is found depending on which page the string is found else it should do nothing.

This is what i got could someone help modify it to get it work the if else pass is the problem for me atm.

```
import urllib
import time
from pushbullet import Device

string = 'this is a test string'
b = 1
phone = Device('APIKEY', 'DeviceKEY')

while b <= 10:
    webpage = urllib.urlopen('http://thisisawebpage.com').read()
    website = urllib.urlopen('http://thisisawebsite.com').read()
    phone.push_note("String Found" , "String Found") if string in webpage else pass
    phone.push_note("String found in Website" , "String found in Website") if string in website else pass
    time.sleep(1800)
```

Comment: Don't use a conditional expression where a regular `if` statement would do. `if string in webpage: phone.push_note(...)`.

Comment: It appears that you don't increment `b` anywhere in the loop, is this what you want?

Comment: If you did want to use a conditional expression here for some reason, you could use `else None` to make it syntactically valid (or really, `else` followed by any value). Or you could use `and`, although that expresses your intent even less clearly.

Answer (score 3):

The `if-else` here is an expression, not a statement, so you cannot use `pass`. The conditional expression is used when you need one of two values, depending on the condition; it is *not* a control-flow statement. Use a proper `if` statement instead.

```
if string in webpage:
    phone.push_note("String Found", "String Found")
if string in website:
    phone.push_note("String found in Website", "String found in Website")
```

If you know Perl, the Python conditional expression looks similar to Perl's `if` statement modifier, but the two are not equivalent. In Perl, something like

```
# This is pseudo-Perl; there is no `in` operator and the Perl replacement
# depends heavily on what $webpage actually is
$phone->push_note("String Found", "String Found") if $string in $webpage;
```

will work, but not in Python.